# How to make background image scale to 100% of height and width even if screen size is not big enough

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Im trying to make my bodys background image to scale to the full resolution even if the window is pinned to the left of my screen on windows, it is 1080p picture, heres an example of what i mean.

full window size

http://gyazo.com/4c2ffe00930d09cec27404ecccdeec18

scaled window size

http://gyazo.com/d5afdbdf43ef1a06ab1d52df6ce956b7

heres my bodys css

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: url('Images/background.png') #A98436 no-repeat left top;
    background-size: 100%;
    font-family: 'ubuntu', 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;

The idea is that you want your image to stay the same size, regardless the resolution.

Answer (score 3):

you can set it to `background-size: cover cover;`

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hh8hj0ez/)**

```
body {
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-image: url('http://i.gyazo.com/4c2ffe00930d09cec27404ecccdeec18.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover cover;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This is correct. the only thing I would add is to add background-position:center center; (but that could depend on the image also).

Comment: Only use one cover: `background-size: cover`

Answer (score 0):

Set min height and width?

min-height: 1920px;
min-width: 1024px;

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp

Comment: It still stays the same, i dont care about the resolution of the image when window is small.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  }
body {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #A98436 url('http://i.gyazo.com/4c2ffe00930d09cec27404ecccdeec18.jpg') no-repeat left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain; /* maintains background-image's ratio while keeping it within body */
    font-family: 'ubuntu', 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

See [background-size - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) for more on background-size.